# How to change the keyboard layout from the Vagrantfile

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, vagrant, jhipster

I'm using the DevBox of JHipster, which is a XUbuntu Vagrant box.

I want to change the keyboard layout during the provisionning of the box, and make it effective even on the login page, without the need of a reboot, so the user can just use it directly after the first start of the VM.

I tried several commands to change the keyboard layout:

- `setxkbmap fr` (won't work since shell provisionning is done with root and setxkbmap can't be used with root)
- `loadkeys fr` (no errors but no result)
- `sed -ie '/^XKBLAYOUT=/s/".*"/"fr"/' /etc/default/keyboard` (apparently works but have to be "sourced")

and several commands to apply the changes:

- `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`
- `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive keyboard-configuration` (`noninteactive` because it is a shell script)
- `setupcon --force` (`force` because without it it complains that it's not a Linux terminal)

None of them worked (or more precisely, the combination of `sed` and `udevadm` seemed to work, but when I tried it with a newly installed VM, it did not).

Any idea on how to make it work ?

EDIT:

Ok it was a serious case of PEBKAC...

For the record, the correct combination for me was: sed -ie '/^XKBLAYOUT=/s/".*"/"fr"/' /etc/default/keyboard && udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change

I just badly refactored the variable containing the language (fr here), so it printed nothing...

EDIT:

Well it wasn't just a PEBKAC, it works fine on the login page but not once I'm logged in (even if it worked before I reinstalled everything).

Comment: did you check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1316913) ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok it was a serious case of PEBKAC...

For the record, the correct combination for me was:
`sed -ie '/^XKBLAYOUT=/s/".*"/"fr"/' /etc/default/keyboard && udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`

I just badly refactored the variable containing the language (`fr` here), so it printed nothing...

---

EDIT: Well it wasn't just a PEBKAC, it works fine on the login page but not once I'm logged in (even if it worked before I reinstalled everything).

Comment: Well it wasn't just a PEBKAC, it works fine on the login page but not once I'm logged in (even if it worked before I reinstalled everything).

Comment: Interesting question, any solution in the way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an **xfce4** you can try this:

```
sudo setxkbmap fr
sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT=\"\w*"/XKBLAYOUT=\"fr\"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

Worked for me but you need to reboot.